# Display Video Thumnail using Flutter video_player

Tags: flutter, dart, thumbnails, flutter-video-player

I have my mobile app successfully displaying my images and videos on my page, but it seems to only show a blank container with play thumbnail for my videos.

```
GridView.builder(
                      gridDelegate:
                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                      ),
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: tickets[widget.indexEvent].videos.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                            height: 220,

                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              /*borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),*/
                              child: Stack(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: 220,
                                    height: 220,
                                    color: colorPrimary,
                                    child: ThumbnailImage(
                                      videoUrl:
                                                  tickets[widget.indexEvent]
                                                      .videos[i],

                                     ),
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    bottom: 50,
                                    right: 50,
                                    child: Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Get.to(
                                            () => NetVideoPlayerScreen(
                                              videoUrl:
                                                  tickets[widget.indexEvent]
                                                      .videos[i],
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                           /* borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(12),*/
                                          ),
                                          child: Icon(
                                            Icons.play_arrow,
                                            color: colorPrimary,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

Sorry for the block of code, but this is the easiest way I feel like I could show some context. I thought my `thumbnailImage()` function could use the video link to generate a thumbnail from the video, but apparently it doesn't have that capability.

Is there a way for me to call a function in flutter's video_player package to return a thumb image using my url? The documentation isn't really helpful for me, and I can't seem to find a way to just evoke it right here in the container code. Thanks!

Comment: Videoplayer should have a thumbnail property. Find that property and put a thumbnail.

Comment: Sulaymon, it seems to not want to show a thumbnail if I have the video in a small thumbnail container. Can you show how to evoke the thumbnail from my code i have shown? I am still having a lot of issues getting this working, sadly